# Request.Files same file getting uploaded asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, file-upload

```
            foreach (string fileName in Request.Files)
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[fileName];

                //Save file content goes here
                fName = file.FileName;
                if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                {


                    subPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SubPath"].ToString() + "/" + currentUserId;
                    bool isExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(subPath));

                    if (!isExists)
                        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(subPath));


                    string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(subPath), System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
                    file.SaveAs(path);



                }

            }
```

If i upload multiple files i get the same file n number of the times.

I am using this control: https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput

My cs.html

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aekqm

Please find above my complete code.

Answer (score 9):

Solved my issue:

Used the code below

```
for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
{
    HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[i];
}
```

instead of the foreach loop which was taking the same file twice

Comment: thanks, yes the `foreach` loop example is floating around for dropzone.js MVC tutorials. Thanks for this snippet, I am sure others will find it useful.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this site](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Mar/06/Using-the-HTML5-input-typefile-multiplemultiple-Tag-in-ASPNET),

> When multiple files are uploaded from a single file control, **they are assigned the same name.**

Answer (score 1):

change this:

```
<input id="file-3" name="files" type="file" multiple>
```

to this:

```
<input id="files" name="files" type="file" multiple="multiple"/>
```

or:

```
<input id="files" name="files" type="file" multiple="true"/>
```

Comment: i do have other form elements also on the top can that be an issue?

Comment: it depends what elements are there you can add it by editing your post

Comment: exclude the library that you are using it should work without that may be that library is causing something go wrong

Comment: its the same only one file posting multiple times?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54390/discussion-between-asp-net-my-life-and-ehsan-sajjad).