# Dynamic name on file upload fields in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I have created a dynamic form generator for my company. It allows the users to create different form fields with different names. Processing the form is easy, but the file upload has been a nightmare, because the name of the form field is not known for the controller.
In my case, the form field can be like this:

```
<input type="file" name="certificate" accept=".pdf" />
```

or

```
<input type="file" name="course-certificate" accept=".pdf, .docx" />
```

it can even have one or more file fields in one form

The problem is that when it goes to the post method after submitting the form, I am supposed to have a parameter for the files. It can either be a single file like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(HttpPostedFileBase file) // For a single file upload
{
}
```

or

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files) // For multiple file uploads
{
}
```

But I need to send the files with random names that can even have a dash in the middle. What is the solution for this?
I don't want to use any kind of jQuery to prepare the form before sending it, I want to be able to send the form as it was reated and receive it in my controler just like that.

Comment: You would need to loop through `Request.Files`

Comment: Gonna try that and I'll tell you, so I can accept your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [`HttpRequest.Files`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.files(v=vs.110).aspx) collection available which represents uploaded files from `<input type="file" />` elements by using form submit. You just need to iterate it using either `for` or `foreach` loop inside controller action marked with `HttpPostAttribute`:

**`for`-loop version**

```
for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
{
    var uploadedFile = Request.Files[i] as HttpPostedFileBase;

    if (uploadedFile.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

**`foreach`-loop version**

```
foreach (string fileName in Request.Files)
{
    var uploadedFile = Request.Files[fileName] as HttpPostedFileBase;

    if (uploadedFile.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

**Note:** With `foreach` loop, if `Request.Files` collection has duplicate file names, the first matched file name will be stored multiple times, even they have different sizes (related issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23857421/request-files-same-file-getting-uploaded-asp-net-mvc)). Hence, `for` loop approach is more preferred (and you can still get corresponding file name with `uploadedFile.FileName`).

Comment: Thanks, I used your solution. Important to notice that the field names (as in the form) are stored in a collection: `Request.Files.AllKeys`